# iOS UPnP Server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, upnp

I wrote a UPnP controller for iOS on Obj-C using cybergarage and now I want to add a UPnP Server for the same app using the same cybergarage library.

But I got a problem: I didnt found any tutorials or good documentation for anything except ControlPoint.

```
CGUpnpDevice *device = [[CGUpnpDevice alloc] initWithXMLDescription: @""];
[device setUdn: @"uuid:0000d8c8-20a0-00d8-9999-4858001808d8"];
[device setDeviceType: @"urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1"];
[device setFriendlyName: @"OMG server by spe"];
[device setUserData: @"omg user"];
[device start];
NSLog(@"running: %i", (bool)[device isRunning]);
```

It says running: 0
I dont know the correct xml for constructor and if I use default constructor

```
[[CGUpnpDevice alloc] init];
```

it crashes.
Is there anybody with cybergarage programming experience? Any ideas how to run the server?

Comment: Can you help me for UPnP server in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

That`s probably due to the Objective-C port since (i guess) it only implements control point.

But you can user C or CC code to guide you. Take a look at the media server sample.

Go to github site: https://github.com/cybergarage/CyberLink4CC/tree/master/sample/media